# Dynamic argument based function call inside controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have following controller Where i run some queries based on variables which comes through ajax. Now my Question is how do i make it more efficient means without checking every if condition can i make it dynamic where it will check the variable and call only that line of statement?

Eg. suppose it has only $category_id & $min_price so it will run only that line of statement so my Query become more faster and also save no_of_statements inside a controller?

```
public function searchByCheckbox(Request $request)
    {  
        if( !empty($request->get('category_id'))|| 
            !empty($request->get('industry_id')) ||
            !empty($request->get('min_price'))      ||
            !empty($request->get('max_price'))  
          )
        {                   

        $query = DB::table('users')
           ->join('products','products.auth_id','users.id')
           ->Join('reviews','products.id','reviews.product_id')
           ->select('products.*','users.avatar',DB::raw('(sum(rating)/count(user_id)) as rating'))             
           ->where('products.status','=','1')           
           ->groupBy('products.id')   
           ->latest();

        if ($request->has('category_id')) {
            $query->WhereIn('products.category_id', $request->get('category_id'));
        }

        if ($request->has('industry_id')) {
            $query->WhereIn('products.industry_id', $request->get('industry_id'));
        }

        if ($request->get('min_price')!='0') {
            $query->Where('products.regular_price','>' ,$request->get('min_price'));
        }

        if ($request->get('max_price')!='0') {
            $query->Where('products.regular_price','<' ,$request->get('max_price'));
        }


        if($request->has('min_price') && $request->has('max_price')){
            $query->whereBetween('products.regular_price',
            [   $request->get('min_price'),
                $request->get('max_price')
            ]);
        }

        if ($request->has('industry_id')&& $request->has('category_id')) 
        {
            $query->orWhereIn('products.industry_id', $request->get('industry_id'));
            $query->orWhereIn('products.category_id', $request->get('category_id'));
        }

        if ($request->has('industry_id')&& $request->has('category_id') && $request->get('min_price')!='0' && $request->get('max_price')!='0') 
        {
            $query->orWhereIn('products.industry_id', $request->get('industry_id'));
            $query->orWhereIn('products.category_id', $request->get('category_id'));
            $query->orwhereBetween('products.regular_price',
            [   $request->get('min_price'),
                $request->get('max_price')
            ]); 
        }

        $products = $query->get();


        }
        else
        {


        $products = DB::table('users')
          ->join('products','products.auth_id','users.id')
          ->Join('reviews','products.id','reviews.product_id')
           ->select('products.*','users.avatar',DB::raw('(sum(rating)/count(user_id)) as rating'))                       
          ->where('products.status','=','1') 
          ->groupBy('products.id')          
         ->latest()
         ->get();  
        }

        return view('cart.ajax.product-result', ['products' => $products]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think dynamic checking would just add unnecessary complexity. I would just make some changes

1. Separate filter data from other data in your request (if you have any). So name for filter fields should be like  `filter['min_price']`.
2. Remove last two if statements because they don't have any sense.

I would do it like this:

```
public function searchByCheckbox(Request $request)
{
    $filter = $request->has('filter')?$request->get('filter'):[];
    $products = [];
    $query = DB::table('users')
        ->join('products','products.auth_id','users.id')
        ->Join('reviews','products.id','reviews.product_id')
        ->select('products.*','users.avatar',DB::raw('(sum(rating)/count(user_id)) as rating'))
        ->where('products.status','=','1')
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->latest();

    if(empty($filter)){
        $products = $query->get();
    }else{
        if(empty($filter['min_price'])){
            $filter['min_price'] = 0;
        }

        if(!empty($filter['category_id'])){
            $query->WhereIn('products.category_id', $filter['category_id']);
        }

        if(!empty($filter['industry_id'])){
            $query->WhereIn('products.industry_id', $filter['industry_id']);
        }

        if(!empty($filter['max_price'])){
            $query->whereBetween('products.regular_price',
                [   $filter['min_price'],
                    $filter['max_price']
                ]);
        }else{
            $query->Where('products.regular_price','>', $filter['min_price']);
        }
    }
    return view('cart.ajax.product-result', ['products' => $products]);
}
```